# Evaluate returns -1 for TRUE? (Why not 1)

Tags: excel, vba

I was helping with another question, and I realized that using `Evaluate` in VBA seems to return `-1` for `TRUE` statements.

Data:

```
Column A    Column B
A           A
A           B
C           C
```

So if I put `=INT(A2=B2)` and drag down, I get `1, 0, 1` which I expect.

However, using the following VBA, I get `-1, 0, -1`.

```
For i = 2 To 4
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Evaluate(Int(Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2)))
Next i
```

Why would `EVALUATE` use `-1` for `TRUE`?

Comment: In VBA -1 is True, 0 is False. Try: `Debug.Print (-1 = True)` and `Debug.Print (0 = False)` to see what I mean

Comment: @RyanWildry Oh, that's odd!  AFAIK, in other languages, `1` is `True`.  Why would VBA/Microsoft flip that around?  I'm quite surprised that `1=True` returns `False`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe this was done for backward compatibility.

Comment: Actually, [Raymond Chen implies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923) that it was just "done". To expand on the comment above, it's specified in OLE automation spec as [VARIANT_BOOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237864.aspx). Since VBA is a COM beastie and uses `Variant`, it's simply following spec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VBA uses -1 for the True value. Cf. C and C++ which use 1.

-1 has all bits set to 1 in a 2’s complement signed integral type so the choice has some sense.

The choice goes way back to DOS BASIC (and other BASICs such as the one on the old BBC Micro) which predates the Component Object Model of the mid 1990s that’s still in use today.

Comment: *"-1 has all bits set to 1 in a 2’s complement signed integral type so the choice has some sense."* - sorry that's just jibberish to me, would you mind putting it in layman's terms for someone like me? :)

Comment: @dwirony: put another way, -1 is the bitwise negation of 0.

Comment: Is there anything in the VBA language, or its use, that would have hinted at `-1` being `TRUE`? I'm just curious because if I had used code elsewhere that relied on `1=TRUE`, would I just have to wait for my code to throw an error to discover this quirk?

Comment: @BruceWayne: You need to have had a warped childhood. Start this BBC Micro Emulator and type `PRINT TRUE`: https://computer-literacy-project.pilots.bbcconnectedstudio.co.uk/jsbeeb/index.html